# Clone Object multiple times and append the clones in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to provide a predefined Object *Grab* to clone it later and populate the clones with further functionality. The problem I am facing is, that I can clone the objects, but only one of them is appended to the DOM afterwards.

The Code so far is:

```
var foo = jQuery.extend({}, Grab);
var bar = jQuery.extend({}, Grab);

$('body').append(foo);
$('body').append(bar);
```

I use *jQuery.extend()* because I need the *.daggable* feature of Grab with the clone.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: You can use `.clone('true', 'true')`

Comment: Is `Grab` a dom element? Use [jQuery `.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: Yes, Grab is a DOM element. It is populated with some css and .draggable() at another place.
To preserve the .draggable() I need to use .extend() instead of .clone(). Otherwise the whole idea of cloning the prepared object would be a waste of energy and I'd produce a lot of redundant code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `Grab` is an element you should normally use `.clone(true, true)` to copy it, not `$.extend()`

The `true` parameters will cause it to be a deep copy of the original object.

However this probably won't correctly copy the *draggable* settings.  Just because the object has been cloned, you're not guaranteed that all of the state has been copied.  In particular if any of the draggable state is stored in lexically scoped private variables it won't work.

Likewise any other setup that the `.draggable` function does the first time it's added to an element won't have been done either.

IMHO, your best bet would be to use `.clone(false)` to make a shallow copy, and then call `.draggable` on the copies, and then re-attach their event handlers.

Comment: Alnitak is correct in that when you use `.clone()` you are copying the element and all classes and properties. If your draggable settings are based on an event handler you you can use the deep copy optional argument to clone the event handlers as well. However, you may still find some issues depending on how you manage the state of the element

Comment: Sorry about some duplicate data in there. I didn't see his edits until I finished writing my comment

Comment: Unfortunately .clone() is no option at this point, because it does not copy the attached events correctly (draggable functionality is lost). It *does* clone the object and lets it be appendable to the DOM though!

Comment: @zoku well if `.clone` doesn't work then `.extend` certainly won't either.  I suggest you just use a shallow `.clone()` and then call `.draggable` again (and reattach events)